# Farey Fractions Estimate Equivalent to the Prime Number Theorem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Wikipedia's article on [Farey Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Riemann_hypothesis) points to an article of Jerome Franel that some averages are equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis.

Let $F_n$ be the $n$-th Farey sequence, then the number of elements in that list is:

$$|\{ (m,n): 0 \leq m, n \leq N \text{ and }\mathrm{gcd}(m,n)=1\}|
= \phi(1) + \dots + \phi(N) $$

Then traversing the Farey sequence in order, we can estimate:

$$ \sum_{k = 1}^{|F_n|} \left(a_k - \frac{k}{|F_n|} \right)^2 = O(n^r) \quad\text{for all } r>-1$$

which is claimed to be equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis (any proof?).

I interpret this as measuring the [discrepancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence) (see also this [book](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/book.html)) between the Farey sequence and a uniformly spaced sequence.

There are lost of statements equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis, but it is far from proven.  Is there a similar or weaker estimate which could be equivalent of the to the Prime Number Theorem?  One equivalent statement is that

$$ \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda(n) = 1 + o(1)$$

In fact, it seems that estimates on the set of primes, control and benchmark our ability to estimate other number-theoretic quantities.  So I am wondering if there is an estimate of Farey fractions that captures similar information.

---

Franel's paper doesn't seem to be on the internet and I don't have access to a University library.

Comment: Have you seen Niederreiter's paper *The distribution of Farey points*, Math. Ann (201)1973), 341-345?  This paper may be open access now.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Yes it's open.  Not with JSTOR but with GDZ http://bit.ly/1JlP0SH

Comment: As for the equivalence of the first statement and Riemann Hypothesis, see http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/fareyproject.pdf which is open access.

Comment: Franel's paper is at http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN00250653X and Landau's at http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002506548

Comment: The Harold M Edwards book, Riemann's Zeta Function, section 12.2, is titled The Riemann HYpothesis and Farey Series, and I think it has a proof of the Franel result.

Comment: The Franel and Landau papers, in English translation, with a discussion of the Franel paper, appear in http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/farey.pdf

Answer (score 14):

I am surprised no one answered this, I just ran across it randomly when I was looking for something else. I have read Franel's paper, and Landau's, which is the next one in the same journal (if you're getting one, you might as well get both). However, those papers are in a box somewhere and I can't find them at the moment. The answer is that yes, the Prime Number Theorem is known to be equivalent to the little-oh estimate
$$\sum_{k=1}^{|F_n|}\left(a_k-\frac{k}{|F_n|}\right)^2=o(1).$$
I think this is proved in Franel's paper. To see that the bound implies the PNT is fairly easy, but to show the reverse implication is not that easy.

A more accessible reference to add to the list already mentioned is Chapter 9 of "The distribution of prime numbers," by M.N. Huxley.